# Minipage spanning across pages

Tags: minipage

I'm looking for a way to span `minipages` across pages in LaTeX.

I have a collection of recipes (presented through the recipe environment provided by the cuisine package) that varies in length, from something like 10 lines to more than can fit on a page. I want to fit as many as possible on one page and span the text across pages only if necessary.
Until now I used the `minipage` environment that is sufficient if the content is not longer than a page.

Is there a way to get a "2 pages"-`minipage` or something similar ?

EDIT:

I have something like : texts A, B, C and D. I don't want them to span across pages if not necessary.

- AAAABB (newpage) BBCCDD is not acceptable
- AAAA (newpage) BBBB (newpage) CCDD is the desirable output

EDIT:

My content is a collection of recipes from the cuisine package.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand the question.  What is the reason to use a minipage in the first place?  What is it about minipage environment that you need?  Are you putting the texts in several columns? Would something like the `flowfram` package (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/flowfram/) help?

Comment: I'm using the minipage environment because it guarantees that the text contained doesn't span pages. But it is too strict for me ...

Comment: Example: assuming "A" means typeset text from recipe (a) of height 1/6th available height, AAAA BBBBCC DD looks like it fits your constraint. Is it acceptable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your specification is too vague. You want to fit as many onto one page as possible, but some are larger than a single page so they should be split. What's the criterion for allowing a split? I'd do something like this:

1. Typeset the recipe in a box and measure it.
2. If it's shorter than some constant length (say 40% the height of the page), then put it in a minipage on the page.
3. If it's longer, insert it onto the page without using minipage (hence allowing it to split)

Here's code to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,environ}
\newsavebox\recipebox
\newlength\recipebreaklength
\setlength\recipebreaklength{0.4\textheight}
\newcommand\typesetrecipe[1]{%
  \par\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1ex}\par
  \BODY
  \par\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1ex}\par
}
\NewEnviron{recipe}{%
  \savebox{\recipebox}{\parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \typesetrecipe{\BODY}%
  }}%
  \ifdim
      \dimexpr\ht\recipebox+\dp\recipebox\relax 
      > \recipebreaklength
    \typesetrecipe{\BODY}%
  \else
    \par\noindent\usebox\recipebox
  \fi
  \bigskip
}
\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
\begin{recipe}\lipsum[2]\end{recipe}
\begin{recipe}\lipsum[3]\end{recipe}
\begin{recipe}\lipsum[4]\end{recipe}
\begin{recipe}\lipsum[5]\end{recipe}
\begin{recipe}\lipsum[6]\end{recipe}
\begin{recipe}\lipsum[7-10]\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't the second occurence of `\typesetrecipe{\BODY}` just be `\unvbox\recipebox`?  Then `\BODY` only gets evaluated once.

Comment: Not the way that I coded it, unfortunately (coz there's another box inside). I always try to use LaTeX idioms for such demonstration code, and to use `\unvbox` I'd need to start from scratch with `\setbox\recipebox=\vbox{\hsize=\linewidth...}` kind of thing. But that would be the better way to do it, I agree.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the text into a `\vbox` and test if it is too long to fit the page.  If not, you can set it, otherwise you can `\vsplit` it across two pages.

I asked a somewhat similar question on SO, [Making Latex typeset given text on two facing pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217516/making-latex-typeset-given-text-on-two-facing-pages); Steve's answer can be tailored for your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `samepage` environment for the stuff you want to stay on the same page. You'll likely need `\raggedbottom` as well.

Comment: I'm using another environment to present my text (recipe) and it doesn't seem to "like" the samepage. The "recipes" are divided between pages.

Comment: That's not really enough information to go on. Can you provide a minimum example that fails with `samepage`?